# How does exactly iterator (of std::map) works in C++?

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator, std

I tried to run following code:

```
std::map < std::string, std::string > m;
m[ "one" ] = "0";
m[ "two" ] = "1";
m[ "three" ] = "2";
m[ "four" ] = "3";

auto it = m.begin();
std::cout << it->first << "\n";
```

The output is: `"four"`. But why does it start from the end? I was expected `"one"`!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) is a sorted container. It sorts its elements, which are key-value pairs, according to the key, which is [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) in your particular case.

Then, strings are lexicographically compared with each other. As the string `four` is the smallest one among all the strings, the pair ("four", "3") becomes the first pair. So `begin()` returns the iterator which points to this pair.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think the std::map sorts the key elements for fast searching. (I believe it uses binary search). If you don't want the order to change you hace to use std::vector  or std::list  or std::deque  something like that.